# how to get duplicate results in mysql output?

Tags: mysql

I have a simple and silly doubt in sql.
I have to write down a query like the one below. 
Here, id is not unique. But when i do the following query i get unique values as output. How do i get multiple values?

```
select name from students_table where id in (select id from students_id);

Ex : Lets say students_table has name   id
                                 -----  ---
                                 john    1
                                 jack    2

     And students_id table has   id    
                                 ---
                                  1
                                  1
                                  1
                                  2
                                  ...

If i write the query in the above way i get name
                                            ----
                                            john
                                            jack

Instead i want my output as name
                            ----
                            john
                            john
                            john
                            jack
```

Comment: check my answer below. i'm pretty sure it worked! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select st.name from students_id si
join students_table st on st.id = si.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `JOIN` both tables. Try this,

```
SELECT  a.Name
FROM    student_table a
        INNER JOIN student_ID b
             on a.ID = b.ID
```

This is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do a join:

```
select t1.name from students_table t1 inner join students_id t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```